# Prove $\chi_A$ is Riemann integrable $\Leftrightarrow$ $\partial{A}$ is a null set

Tags: real-analysis

Using $\chi_A$ to denote the characteristic function of a $\textbf{bounded}$ set $A\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\partial{A}$ to denote the boundary of $A$ (strictly $\partial{A}=\{a:\forall\epsilon>0,B(a,\epsilon)\cap A\ne\emptyset\land B(a,\epsilon)\not\subset A\}$ ).

> Please prove
>   $\chi_A$ is Riemann integrable  $\Leftrightarrow$ $\partial{A}$ is a null set(with lebesgue measure)

I know is true for those $\partial{A}$ is a null set in the sense of Riemann, but have no idea in the sense of Lebesgue. Maybe there is a way to construct finite many sets with arbitrary small measure from those countable many sets.
Another questions on this site says it's a theorem, but I want wo know it in detail.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a null set in the sense of Riemann ? How do you Riemann-integrate a function defined on $\mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: @elidiot A set can be coverd by a union of finite many rectangle whose measure is arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that a bounded function is Riemann-integrable if and only if its set of discontinuities has measure zero,(i.e., for every $\varepsilon>0$ it can be covered by a union of measurable sets whose measures sum up to less than $\varepsilon$). Now, the set of discontinuities of the characteristic function $\chi_A$ is precisely the boundary $\partial A$. The result follows.

Comment: I think you only explain the $\Rightarrow$. In the sense of Riemann means the union must be finite.

Comment: The claim you set out to prove holds for the Lebesgue measure. There is no "sense of Riemann" involved. "null set" refers to having measure equal to zero, in the sense of Lebesgue.

Comment: Sorry for my rudeness, I get confused with those concepts because I have only learned Lebesgue integral. I guess I should learn Riemann intergral step by step.